# how to uncheck few checkboxes from already checked list of checkboxes in javascript/playwright

Tags: javascript, checkbox, playwright

Im new to Javascript/Playwright, I have a scenario where I want to uncheck few checkboxes( e.g `1,3,5 8` checkboxes ) from already pre-selected checkbox list(10 checkboxes)

I tried to uncheck all checkboxes and check only required, this approach is working fine but would like to know if there is a better way to achieve this in javascript

```
let role ='checkbox';
    async uncheckAll(role)
    {
      const checkboxes = this.page.getByRole(`${role}`);
      for (const checkbox of await checkboxes.all())
      await checkbox.uncheck();
     }
```

Comment: simply use a form reset... ?

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Locator filters](https://playwright.dev/docs/locators#filtering-locators) to narrow down locator list to select few by combining multiple locator properties.

Example:

```
  await page
    .getByRole('listitem')
    .filter({ hasText: 'SomeDistinguishingText' })
    .getByRole(`${role}`, { name: 'Something' })
    .uncheck();
```